# A stochastic Process where $X_{T_A}\not \in A$. Must it always be in $\bar A$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

So, I was wondering how to define a stochastic process $X$, with continuous paths, such that $X_{T_A}\not \in A$, where $T_A=\inf\{t>0:X_t \in A\}$.

For this, I was thinking of $X$ mimicking the behaviour of $\sin(1/t)$...

Also, is it true that we always have $X_{T_A}\in \bar A$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Sorry and thanks! Yes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we will always have $X_{T_A} \in \overline A$ because $X$ has continuous paths.  For a specific example, you could do something as simple as $X_t = t$ and $A = (1,2)$.

EDIT:  To prove $X_{T_A} \in \overline A$, from the definition of $T_A$ we have that there exist $(t_n)$ decreasing to $T_A$ such that $X_{t_n} \in A$.  Since $X$ has continuous paths, $(X_{t_n}) \rightarrow X_{T_A},$ and since $X_{T_A}$ is the limit of points in $A$ we have $X_{T_A} \in \overline A$.

Comment: Thanks, for the example! And how would we prove that for the general case?

Comment: Added to the answer!

Answer (score 1):

On the condition that $T_A<\infty$.
By definition of $T_A$, there is a sequence of times $\tau_1,...,\tau_n$ such that:

- $X_{\tau_n} \in A$
- $\tau_n \longrightarrow T_A$

By the (right) continuity of $X$, $X_{T_A} = \lim X_{\tau_n}$.
By definition of $\overline{A}$, $\lim X_{\tau_n} \in \overline{A}$
Hence the conclusion.

Comment: Am I thinking correctly in assuming that the sequence of times will be decreasing?

Comment: Sure, if you want it to be that way. You can just get rid of the randomness in your definition by considering any $\omega$ such that $T_A(\omega)<+\infty$. It's much clearer to reason that way.

Comment: Thanks ;) the +1 was mine